# Camel RabbitMQ concurrent consumer dropping messages on shutdown

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I'm connecting to a RabbitMQ cluster with 50 messages on a queue waiting to be processed by my Java application running Camel.
My Camel URI is `rabbitmq://localhost:5672/PrintRequest?autoAck=false&autoDelete=false&automaticRecoveryEnabled=true&concurrentConsumers=5&durable=true&exchangeType=fanout&password=rabbitPass&prefetchCount=5&prefetchEnabled=true&queue=server-1-PrintRequest&threadPoolSize=5&topologyRecoveryEnabled=true&username=rabbitUser` which in theory should pull 5 messages of the queue in 5 threads and process them. The time to process each event takes a few seconds on average.

When I stop the application gracefully whilst it is processing the events, I expect to see it place the events which it has not finished processing back on the queue (moved out of the unacked state to the ready state). However the application discards these events and more, sometimes even all 50 of the events during the shutdown with the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Run not allowed as ShutdownStrategy is forcing shutting down, will reject executing exchange: Exchange[]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.continueProcessing(CamelInternalProcessor.java:266)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.process(DefaultAsyncProcessorAwaitManager.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.support.AsyncProcessorSupport.process(AsyncProcessorSupport.java:40)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.doHandleDelivery(RabbitConsumer.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitConsumer.handleDelivery(RabbitConsumer.java:79)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I reduce the concurrent consumers to one I get the expected behaviour of "put back the unprocessed messages to the ready state", however I require this to be concurrent to keep up with the rate of events coming in.

I am using the 3.6.0 version of Camel and using the default shutdown strategy. The exception appear 3 seconds after I SIGTERM the process.

Comment: What Camel version are you using? And what shutdown timeout do you have configured? And when you see that exception above, after how long time since you stopped Camel do you see that?

Comment: @ClausIbsen I am using the 3.6.0 version of Camel and using the default shutdown strategy. The exception appears 3 seconds after I SIGTERM the process.

Comment: Can you put together a reproducer example we can use to help look into this? You can put it up on github or create a JIRA ticket and attach a .zip file. And kindly with instructions how to run the reproducer, thanks.